# How to add extension(.asp) to ASP.Net development Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp-classic

How to add extension(.asp) to ASP.Net development Server.

Basically I need to use asp files in my VS 2010 development. While running the code the application goes to ASP.Net development server(defaultly from .Net) and running. There I dont have .asp as extension.

Please give me the way to do the same.

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: Have you tried [google](http://www.google.co.il/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=IIS+install+asp.net) ?

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET Development Server does not support Classic ASP.